# view search not found in table using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

ma'am/ sir i have a problem, i want to view "Search Not Found" inside my table but when click the search button, it will go to the blank page with that search not found:

this is my model:

```
function search($keyword)
{
    $this->db->like('Firstname',$keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('Middlename',$keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('Lastname',$keyword);
    $this->db->or_like('Idnumber',$keyword);
    $query  =   $this->db->get('studentinformation');
    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
            return $query->result();
    else
    return FALSE;
}
```

This is my controller:

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];
    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['results']    =   $this->model_adminlogin->search($keyword);
    if ( !empty($data) ) 
         echo  'Search not found';
    else
                $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
}
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="z table-responsive">
    <table class=" table table-hover">         
        <thead >
            <tr>
                <th>ID Number</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Middle name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Sex</th>     
            </tr>
        </thead><?php   
            if ( !empty($data) ) 
            echo  'Search not found';
            else
            {
                <tbody>
                    foreach($results as $row)
                    { ?>
                            <tr>                             
                                <td><?php echo $row-> Idnumber ?></td>
                                <td class="text-capitalize "><?php echo $row -> Firstname ?></td>
                                <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row->Middlename ?></td>
                                <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Lastname ?></td>
                                <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Sex?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="<?php echo site_url('viewstudentinalpha/viewspecific/'.$row->Id) ?>" class="btn btn-info " style="font-size: 18px;" type="submit" name="submit" role="button">Option</a>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                    }           
      } ?>
        </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This coding

**Controller**

```
  function search_keyword()
        {
      $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

                $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];

               $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');

           $data['results']    =   $this->model_adminlogin->search($keyword);
         if ( empty($data['results']) ) 
    {
             $data['message'] = 'Search not found';

    }
 $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
    }
```

**View Coding**

```
<div class="z table-responsive" >
            <table class=" table table-hover"  >


                 <thead >
                             <tr >

                                   <th>ID Number</th>
                                   <th>First name</th>
                                   <th>Middle name</th>
                                   <th>Last name</th>
                                   <th>Sex</th>

                           </tr>
                      </thead>
                    <tbody>

    <?php if ( isset($message) ):
         echo  "<tr>".$message."</tr>";

    else:   foreach($results as $row):?>





          <tr>


                  <td><?php echo $row-> Idnumber ?></td>
                  <td class="text-capitalize "><?php echo $row -> Firstname ?></td>
                   <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row->Middlename ?></td>
                   <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Lastname ?></td>
                   <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Sex?></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('viewstudentinalpha/viewspecific/'.$row->Id) ?>" class="btn btn-info " style="font-size: 18px;" type="submit" name="submit" role="button">Option</a>

                             </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>




              <?php endforeach; endif; ?>





            </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
```

Comment: You dont want to have the Tbody in the foreach

Comment: i have a  problem, i want to put inside the table like below in id, firstname .....

Comment: Are you want common display "search not found" text below the table fields ?

Answer (score 1):

Try To Change the following Code in the View File:

```
<div class="z table-responsive" >
            <table class=" table table-hover"  >


                 <thead >
                             <tr >

                                   <th>ID Number</th>
                                   <th>First name</th>
                                   <th>Middle name</th>
                                   <th>Last name</th>
                                   <th>Sex</th>

                           </tr>
                      </thead>

    <?php



           if ( !isset($results) ) 
{
         echo  'Search not found';

       }  else{   foreach($results as $row){

                            ?>




    <tbody>
          <tr>


                  <td><?php echo $row-> Idnumber ?></td>
                  <td class="text-capitalize "><?php echo $row -> Firstname ?></td>
                   <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row->Middlename ?></td>
                   <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Lastname ?></td>
                   <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Sex?></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('viewstudentinalpha/viewspecific/'.$row->Id) ?>" class="btn btn-info " style="font-size: 18px;" type="submit" name="submit" role="button">Option</a>

                             </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>




              <?php
              }


       }

                         ?>




            </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

**Controller**

```
 function search_keyword()
 {
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

    $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];

    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');

    $data['results']    =   $this->model_adminlogin->search($keyword);
    if ($data['result'] == FALSE ) 
    {
      $data['message'] = 'Search not found';

      $this->load->view('result_view',$data);

    }else{
      $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
 } 
}
```

**view**

```
<div class="z table-responsive" >
     <table class=" table table-hover"  >
        <thead >
            <tr >
               <th>ID Number</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Middle name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Sex</th>

            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
    <?php

        if(isset($result)){
          foreach($results as $row){
         ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row-> Idnumber ?></td>
        <td class="text-capitalize "><?php echo $row -> Firstname ?></td>
        <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row->Middlename ?></td>
        <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Lastname ?></td>
        <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Sex?></td>
        <td>
             <a href="<?php echo site_url('viewstudentinalpha/viewspecific/'.$row->Id) ?>" class="btn btn-info " style="font-size: 18px;" type="submit" name="submit" role="button">Option</a>
        </td>
     </tr>
   <?php
    } }
    if(isset($meassge))
    {
        echo $message;
    }  
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```